# Error in the code

Tags: c#, console

Im trying to run this simple **C#** code

```
   Line 1     Console.Write("Enter N:-");
   Line 2     int N =  Console.Read();           
   Line 3     Console.WriteLine("Enter AP:-");
   Line 4     string[] APa = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');            
   Line 5     int A = Convert.ToInt16(APa[0]);
   Line 6     int D = Convert.ToInt16(APa[1]) - Convert.ToInt16(APa[0]);
   Line 7     int L = Convert.ToInt16(APa[APa.Length - 1]);
   Line 8     Console.WriteLine("N:-" + N + " A:-" + A + " D:-" + D + " L:-" + L);
```

After i enter the value of N, the program execution should stop to read the value of variable **APa** at **Line 4**, but its not stopping there and I am getting error at **Line 5**.

What I am wrong?

Comment: Console.Read() doesn't do what you think it does.  Use int N = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()) instead.  You'll eventually discover the TryParse() method.

Answer (score 2):

You're using the wrong method for accepting input, on the second line. Every call to [`Console.Read()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.read.aspx) reads in the next character from the standard input, while [`Console.ReadLine()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.console.readline.aspx) reads an entire line in.

Change this:

```
int N = Console.Read();
```

To this:

```
int N = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

The issue will be more obvious if you enter a value like "413" at the first prompt. Since `Read()` reads in only the first character, the value stored in `N` will be the ASCII value for 4, which is 52. Then `Console.ReadLine()` reads in the rest of the characters in the current line, which is "13", instead of prompting you for another value.

Comment: Thank You, understand the problem now :)